Complex integral (residue method) in lattice quantum field theory
I was studying this reference https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.00483 and i'm stucked on this passage: at page 5 it defines $\mathcal{M}_{2L}$ in a $\lambda\phi^4$ theory and then he says to perform the integral on the $k_0$ dimension (after exchanging the sum with the intgral sum difference). I thought that the best way to perform the integral is via residue method, but i cant get to the result. I reproduce my passages below.
$$\mathcal{M}_{2L}\equiv-i\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{2} \int{\frac{dk^0}{2\pi}}\frac{1}{L^3}\sum_{\vec{k}} \frac{i}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}\frac{i}{(P-k)^2-m^2+i\epsilon}+...+\mathcal{O}\left(\lambda^3\right). \tag{4}$$
So, using the dispersion relation, one can find the poles in $k^0=\pm(\omega_k-i\epsilon)$ and $k^0=P^0\pm(\omega_{P-k}-i\epsilon)$, where ${\omega_k}^2=\vec{k}^2+m^2$.
I have chosen the poles above the real axes closing the contour of my integration path with the superior semicircunference. The two residue that I found are
$$Res(k^0=\omega_k)=\frac{1}{2\omega_k((\omega_k-P^0)^2-\omega_{P-k}^2)}$$ and $$Res(k^0=P^0+\omega_{P-k})=\frac{1}{2\omega_{P-k}((\omega_{P-k}-P^0)^2-\omega_k^2)}$$
Summing these two terms and multiplying by $2\pi i$, i don't get the correct result which should be at the same order in $\lambda$
$$i\mathcal{M}_{2L}=-i\lambda-i\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\frac{1}{L^3}\sum_{\vec{k}}\frac{1}{2\omega_k2\omega_{P-k}(P_0-\omega_k-\omega_{P-k}+i\epsilon)}$$
I focused myself on the computation I can't reproduce, I hope that it is clear enough.

I posted here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/835207/zero-component-of-quadri-momenta-and-dispersion-relation-for-2-to-2-scattering a comment to this question
