Zero-component of quadri-momenta and dispersion relation for 2-to-2 scattering
I posted this question yesterday, Complex integral (residue method) in lattice quantum field theory and I found out a way the integral will be solved as in the reference, but to do that, I should assume that the relation $P_0=\omega_k+\omega_{P-k}$ is valid, where $P_0$ (otherways $E$) is the $0$ component of the total momenta of a 2 in 2 scattering and $\omega_k=\sqrt{\vec{k}^2+m^2}$. I must admit that this type of relation involving the quadri-momentum is not very clear to me, in particular I don't get if the relation involving $\omega_k$ (which, maybe wrongly, i would define as a dispersion relation) is valid only for on-shell particle or it is always valid, and which is the relation between the zero component of the momentum of a particle and his $\omega$ (should I call it "frequency"?).
Thanks for who will answer, I hope the question is clear, and report me if I should clearify some aspects or notation.
